# How to use OOP design patterns to merge two similar functions?

Tags: php, oop

I have two the similar functions, that do verification by generated code. they differ only in body. But logic of them are similar.

```
public function verifyEmail($code){
    // Validaton $code
    // Query to DB to get code
    // Comparing $code with code from DB
    // return success or fail
}

public function verifyPhone($code){
    // Validaton $code
    // Query to DB to get code
    // Comparing $code with code from DB
    // return success or fail
}
```

How can I combine two similar functions, in this case?

Comment: I don't get it. OOP means you have an programming object that simulates a real life object, like a user. You'd have a user and when you add a phone to it, you'l verify it as a method or something.

Comment: put a `class` around it.

Comment: I am not sure where does OOP come into the picture here. Do you have a class whose object your are planning to use. You can always combine these two functions into one by adding a 2nd argument for verification type (phone/email)

Comment: OP I'm sorry, stackoverflow only issues downvotes now. Try going to softwareengineering.stackexchange.com

Comment: I have class, but I demonstrated only methods of class

Comment: @SanchkeDellowar: This question is too vague for Software Engineering.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Take these two:

```
public function verifyEmail($code){
  // Validaton $code
  // Query to DB to get code
  // Comparing $code with code from DB
  // return success or fail
}

public function verifyPhone($code){
  // Validaton $code
  // Query to DB to get code
  // Comparing $code with code from DB
  // return success or fail
}
```

and make this one:

```
public function verifyCol($code, $col){

  // white list the column to use in the query to the DB
  // here is an example of a two item white list
  $column = ($col=='Email') ? 'Email' : 'Phone';

  // Validaton $code
  // Query to DB to get code
  // but use the $column variable to select the proper column

  // Comparing $code with code from DB
  // return success or fail
}
```

also, you can avoid updating legacy code by doing this:

```
public function verifyEmail($code){
  return verifyCol($code, 'Email');
}
public function verifyPhone($code){
  return verifyCol($code, 'Phone');
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't know about using OOP to your advantage, I think using procedural thinking is what you want.

```
private function vertifyThing($type, $code)
{
    // Validaton $code (based off of $type)
    // Query to DB to get code (based off of $type)
    // Comparing $code with code from DB (based off of $type)
    // return success or fail 
}

public function verifyEmail($code)
{
    return vertifyThing('email', $code);
}

public function verifyPhone($code)
{
    return vertifyThing('phone', $code);
}
```

Comment: This is better than was, but I need to use OOP. But in `vertifyThing` I will be forced to use again `if`. This is problem